# Hibernate creates multiple in memory databases

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, tomcat, jpa

I have Spring / hibernate (with cache) based application, it uses in memory database for tests. I have two files that are executed when the application starts schema.sql (schema) & test-data.sql (example data). However, hibernate creates it's own in memory instances and the content previously added is not there. Either it drops the original database or create a second instance and ignores the one created by spring.

small piece of logs where it shows that it creates the DB connection, later creates second one, and again one more(outside the logs):

```
2015-02-17 18:1948 DEBUG DataSourceUtils:110 - Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
**2015-02-17 18:1948 DEBUG SimpleDriverDataSource:138 - Creating new JDBC Driver Connection to [jdbc:h2:mem:dataSource;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=false]**
2015-02-17 18:1948 INFO  ScriptUtils:432 - Executing SQL script from class path resource [dbScripts/schema.sql]
2015-02-17 18:1948 DEBUG ScriptUtils:463 - 0 returned as updateCount for SQL: CREATE table players ( id BIGINT not null, version INTEGER not null, playerid VARCHAR(225) not null, name VARCHAR(225) not null, PRIMARY KEY (id) )
2015-02-17 18:1948 INFO  ScriptUtils:491 - Executed SQL script from class path resource [dbScripts/schema.sql] in 13 ms.
2015-02-17 18:1948 INFO  ScriptUtils:432 - Executing SQL script from class path resource [dbScripts/test-data.sql]
2015-02-17 18:1948 DEBUG ScriptUtils:463 - 1 returned as updateCount for SQL: INSERT INTO players (id, version, playerid, name) VALUES (1, 1, 'bobstone', 'Bob Stone')
2015-02-17 18:1948 DEBUG ScriptUtils:463 - 1 returned as updateCount for SQL: INSERT INTO players (id, version, playerid, name) VALUES (2, 1, 'billbrown', 'Bill Brown')
2015-02-17 18:1948 DEBUG ScriptUtils:463 - 1 returned as updateCount for SQL: INSERT INTO players (id, version, playerid, name) VALUES (3, 1, 'andrewfox', 'Andrew Fox')
2015-02-17 18:1948 DEBUG ScriptUtils:463 - 1 returned as updateCount for SQL: INSERT INTO players (id, version, playerid, name) VALUES (4, 1, 'paulprice', 'Paul Price')
2015-02-17 18:1948 DEBUG ScriptUtils:463 - 1 returned as updateCount for SQL: INSERT INTO players (id, version, playerid, name) VALUES (5, 1, 'annatimes', 'Anna Times')
2015-02-17 18:1948 DEBUG ScriptUtils:463 - 1 returned as updateCount for SQL: INSERT INTO players (id, version, playerid, name) VALUES (6, 1, 'jeffgray', 'Jeff Gray')
2015-02-17 18:1948 DEBUG ScriptUtils:463 - 1 returned as updateCount for SQL: INSERT INTO players (id, version, playerid, name) VALUES (7, 1, 'peterblack', 'Peter Black')
2015-02-17 18:1948 DEBUG ScriptUtils:463 - 1 returned as updateCount for SQL: INSERT INTO players (id, version, playerid, name) VALUES (8, 1, 'colinstewart', 'Colin Stewart')
2015-02-17 18:1948 INFO  ScriptUtils:491 - Executed SQL script from class path resource [dbScripts/test-data.sql] in 7 ms.
2015-02-17 18:1948 DEBUG DataSourceUtils:327 - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
2015-02-17 18:1948 DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:248 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor'
2015-02-17 18:1948 DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:478 - Finished creating instance of bean 'dataSource'
2015-02-17 18:1948 DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:248 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor'
2015-02-17 18:1948 DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:450 - Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter#c0d1f74'
2015-02-17 18:1948 DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:248 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor'
2015-02-17 18:1948 DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:478 - Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter#c0d1f74'
2015-02-17 18:1948 DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:1608 - Invoking afterPropertiesSet() on bean with name 'emf'
2015-02-17 18:1948 DEBUG PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver:536 - Looking for matching resources in jar file [file:/C:/Java/STS/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/players-web/WEB-INF/lib/players-dao-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar]
2015-02-17 18:1948 DEBUG PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver:423 - Resolved location pattern [classpath*:com/test/players/domain/**/*.class] to resources [URL [jar:file:/C:/Java/STS/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/players-web/WEB-INF/lib/players-dao-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/com/test/players/domain/Player.class]]
2015-02-17 18:1948 INFO  LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean:339 - Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
Feb 17, 2015 6:19:48 PM org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper logPersistenceUnitInformation
INFO: HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
Feb 17, 2015 6:19:49 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.8.Final}
Feb 17, 2015 6:19:49 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Feb 17, 2015 6:19:49 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Feb 17, 2015 6:19:49 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
**2015-02-17 18:1949 DEBUG SimpleDriverDataSource:138 - Creating new JDBC Driver Connection to [jdbc:h2:mem:dataSource;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=false]**
Feb 17, 2015 6:19:49 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
Feb 17, 2015 6:19:49 PM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory <init>
INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
```

app-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd">

    <import resource="classpath:spring/hibernate/hibernate-context.xml"/>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />   

    <context:annotation-config/>

    <beans profile="prod">
        <jee:jndi-lookup expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        id="dataSource" jndi-name="java:comp/env/jdbc/players_db"/>
    </beans>

    <beans profile="test">
        <jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource" type="H2">
            <jdbc:script location="classpath:dbScripts/schema.sql"/>
            <jdbc:script location="classpath:dbScripts/test-data.sql"/>
        </jdbc:embedded-database>
    </beans>  

</beans>
```

hibernate-context.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.test.players.service.jpa"/>  

    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.test.players.repository"
                      entity-manager-factory-ref="emf"
                      transaction-manager-ref="transactionManager"/>

    <beans profile="hibernate">

        <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
            <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="emf"/>
        </bean>

        <bean id="emf" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
            <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
                <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
            </property>        
            <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.test.players.domain"/>
            <property name="jpaProperties">
                <props>
                    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">
                        org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
                    </prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.max_fetch_depth">
                        3
                    </prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size">
                        50
                    </prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">
                        10
                    </prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">
                        true
                    </prop> 
                    <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">
                        create
                    </prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">
                        true
                    </prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">
                        org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider
                    </prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">
                        org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory
                    </prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">
                        true    


          </prop>
                 <prop key="net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName">
                    /spring/hibernate/hibernate-cache.xml
                 </prop>
            </props>        
        </property>
    </bean>    

</beans>
```

hibernate-cache.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ehcache 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ehcache.xsd" 
    updateCheck="true"
    monitoring="autodetect" 
    dynamicConfig="true">

    <diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir\ehcache" />

    <defaultCache 
        maxEntriesLocalHeap="1000" 
        eternal="false"
        timeToIdleSeconds="120" 
        timeToLiveSeconds="120" 
        diskSpoolBufferSizeMB="30"
        maxEntriesLocalDisk="10000" 
        diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="120"
        memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU" 
        statistics="true">
        <persistence strategy="localTempSwap" />
    </defaultCache>

    <cache 
        name="players" 
        maxEntriesLocalHeap="1000" 
        eternal="false"
        timeToIdleSeconds="5" 
        timeToLiveSeconds="10">
        <persistence strategy="localTempSwap" />
    </cache>

    <cache 
        name="org.hibernate.cache.internal.StandardQueryCache"
        maxEntriesLocalHeap="5" 
        eternal="false" 
        timeToLiveSeconds="120">
        <persistence strategy="localTempSwap" />
    </cache>

    <cache 
        name="org.hibernate.cache.spi.UpdateTimestampsCache"
        maxEntriesLocalHeap="5000" 
        eternal="true">
        <persistence strategy="localTempSwap" />
    </cache>
</ehcache>
```

and the log showing the problem

Comment: I'm using spring 4.1.4.RELEASE, Hibernate 4.3.8.Final, EhCache 2.6.9, spring-data-jpa 1.7.2.RELEASE

Answer (score 2):

You are asking Spring to create and populate the database and you also have the following telling Hibernate to create the schema:

```
<prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
```

which doesn't really make sense.
Try changing to validate:

```
<prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">validate</prop>
```

Comment: Actually it was another guy that put here his answer but deleted it later for some reason, I had to use  <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files"> because hibernate was overriding the db created by spring